# Fetching parent's function from parent

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I override a function, but would like to get hold of the parent's function from within the parent.

```
>>> class a:
...     def __init__(self):
...             print(self.f)
...     def f(self):
...             pass
...
>>> class b(a):
...     def __init__(self):
...             super(b, self).__init__()
...     def f(self):
...             pass
...
>>> b()
<bound method b.f of <__main__.b object at 0x000002E297A96160>>
```

I'd like the printout to say `a.f`.

Comment: So we can avoid an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what's the *actual* problem you're trying to solve? An instance of `b` *should* see its own implementation of `f` first.

Comment: I'm working on some optimizing code. This is the *actual* problem.

Comment: That's really added no more information. Unless you want to be explicit (`print(a.f)`), you can't.

Comment: Because class `b` inherits class `a`'s methods `f()` becomes a method of `b`. I am incredibly unsure of the issue at hand. What is your end goal?

Comment: Do you want `self.f()` (or something like it) from within `class a` to call `a.f` or do you literally want `print(self.f)` to print `a.f`?

Comment: @unutbu: If I wanted the printout, I would have hardcoded it. ;)  I want `a.f` tucked away for later use. I'm going to use the functor instead of an `if` statement to reduce execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) to make `self.__f` refer to `A.__f` from within `A`'s class definition.

> Name mangling is helpful for letting subclasses override methods without breaking intraclass method calls

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__f()

    def f(self):
        print('A.f')

    __f = f   # Private copy of A's `f` method

class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()

    def f(self):
        print('B.f')

b = B()
b.f()
```

prints

```
A.f
B.f
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def f(self):
        print 'Parent Method...'

class b(a):
    def __init__(self):
        super(b, self).__init__()
        a.f(self) #referance the parent class rather than the child class, because the child overrides the parent method.
        self.f()

    def f(self):
        print "Childs Method..."


b()
```

Comment: As the questions states, "from parent." You're calling `a.f` from the child class `b`.